# ImportError: cannot import name 'DictType' from 'types'

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

```
import pandas as pd
import pandapower as pp
import control
import timeseries
import inspect
```

I get this error for the Timeseries package on Anaconda with Spyder IDE. I'm running a Python version 3.7.4 and Anaconda 4.7.12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon looking at the `timeseries` [pypi entry](https://pypi.org/project/timeseries/) and [github repo](https://github.com/chriso/timeseries), it seems there's only ever been one official release.

The error you're seeing originates in [this file](https://github.com/chriso/timeseries/blob/master/timeseries/time_series.py#L26), and you should be able to fix it by removing the import statement (line 1), and replacing line 26 with

```
if isinstance(points, dict):
```

You can make this change locally by actually changing the file as it's stored locally - the module's folder should be in `{folder your python3.7 is installed in}/lib/site-packages` or `.../lib/python3.7`, depending on what operating system you're on. If this fix works, you might consider submitting a pull request to the original git repository with the change.

---

However, given the age of the module and the apparent lack of support, you might consider using a different module for your time-series data analysis. [A quick google search](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/time_series/time_series_python_libraries.htm) shows that `matplotlib`, `numpy`, `scipy`, `scikit-learn`, and `pandas` are all reputable, well-supported packages that are useful for processing time-series data, and if you have problems while making whatever it is you're making, you're more likely to find effective help when using these more popular tools.